# app:passwordToggleEnabled="true" not working

Tags: java, android, passwords, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I am trying to implement a login page and this is my `TextInputLayout` for the password field.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/eye_outline"
        android:theme="@style/GFSTextInputLayoutTheme"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/light_grey"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

But somehow the `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` doesn't seem to work.

[image]

Here are my gradle imports:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Edit:

styles.xml

```
<style name="GFSTextInputLayoutTheme" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/light_grey</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/light_grey</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/light_grey</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/gfs_blue</item>
</style>
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: the same code is working find in my device share your `@style/GFSTextInputLayoutTheme` theme with question

Comment: @NileshRathod added the layout theme in the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was there all this time but it was white so I couldn't see it. I just included this one line of code:

```
app:passwordToggleTint="@color/blue"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dear @Dale Julian there is no need to put       app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/eye_outline". Android will take it directly from android resources.

Comment: even if I remove that it still won't work. I just tried to manually add a drawable if it will work. But unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Your code seems correct only i tried also, working fine with me. Can you please try again after removing app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/eye_outline"
        android:theme="@style/GFSTextInputLayoutTheme" these lines of code.

Comment: still didn't work. I will try this with a new project.